# How to get list of input in select2 multiple tags

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to get the list of email id's that i have input in my select2 input box.
here is my view
[UI of my select2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YhOc.png)

I want to get the list of emails that i have entered in input box and then i want to send that in ajax call.

here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-9">
  <div class="input-holder">
        <select class="mail-input select-2-input" multiple="multiple">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js

```
 $(".select-2-input").select2({
    tags : true,
    placeholder : "Enter Business Email",
    tokenSeparators : [ ',', ' ' ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get data from select2

```
console.log($(".select-2-input").select2('data'));
```

Get value

```
console.log($(".select-2-input").select2("val"));
```